# iOS "Gboard" app, UIKeyboard notification height is wrong or invalid

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard, nsnotifications

I'm trying to move the view up when the keyboard pops up over the `UITextfield` which is placed on `UIScrollView`. I'm using `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` for this.

It's working perfectly when using `iOS Keyboard` where I'm getting the height `297`.

My client is using the `Gboard keyboard`, he complained that the view is not moving. When I tested, I'm getting the keyboard height as `44`.

I've tried both keys `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` for the `NSNotifiction userInfo` object. Both are giving `44` only.

I tried with `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` also, still same issue.

Could anyone help me with this..?

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813339/move-a-view-up-only-when-the-keyboard-covers-an-input-field/32555911#32555911 it might help

Comment: @MrH, Thanks for the link :)... i've tried, but it's not working with `UITableview`. I've both `UIScrollView` and `UITableView`

Comment: please include code to get keyboard height in above question

Comment: Use TPKeyboardManager. It works for both table view and scroll view.

Comment: Hm for custom keyboards the UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey should work.. Are you sure when you use UIKeyboardDidShowNotification and UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey it's still wrong?

Perhaps this link might help as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402281/convert-uikeyboardframeenduserinfokey-to-view-or-window-coordinates

Comment: Also had this problem with RxKeyboard and Gboard, somewhat fixed it by using keyboard `frame` and not `willShowVisibleHeight` driver.

Answer (score 2):

Its late, but `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` is what U want.